# Total / Lifetime Sales on Magento Dashboard is incorrect

Tags: magento

After updating from Magento 1.2 to 1.4 I noticed that the Lifetime Sales amount was incorrect (other sales reports are fine). Even after making a fake order the Lifetime Sales didn't change. I tried refreshing statistics but nothing happened. Searching the web for this problem turned up a lot of people with the same issue but no solutions. Any suggestions?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about what is wrong. Is the total 0? Is your test order not changing the total? Is the total miscalculating special prices? How do you actually know the total is wrong?

Comment: I know the total is wrong because I know how much the total was before updating. The total is not 0. The test order was added after changing the state to Processing. See my own answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fake order was added to Lifetime Sales after changing the state from Pending to Processing (or Shipped). Therefore my guess is that Magento changed the way it calculates Lifetime Sales and doesn't take Pending orders into account (any more). Any other small differences are due to the fact that Taxes and Shipping are not included in Lifetime Sales.